# Using ajax request in Google extensions - basic knowledge ? Performance

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am creating google chome extension and everything is fine, but i need to know the way to use ajax requests more freely, it should be in the same domain (request) or in the file of the extension directory.

For example i have tried :

```
var heroPage = "";
$.get('/hero.php', function(data) {
    heroPage = data;
});

var townPage = "";
$.get('/town.php', function(data) {
    townPage = data;
});
```

And then i try to use the data in the mouseover listener, and the first one works every second time, but the second does not work at all...it may be something with some limitations or etc.

Is there a way to use for example php file with requests in chrome extensions (in the extension directory), or use some kind of different requests or in the different way ?
I need to get at least 5 requests on page load or even near it and store some data in local-storage or etc., and just cant make it work...

Thank you for you help ! answer will be selected for those who is helping for points ;)

Basically what i need is to fetch infromation from webpage html and store it in local-storage but to fetch from few pages at almost same time. ?

Answer to one of the answer and maybe more clear explanation : 
Hey thanks for answer but it was not what i meant, maybe i did not explained it clearly. What i meant is : I am having a problem with the link you send with http request (because i am doing like so now) that it works only with one request per some time or etc. and i need to fetch html from five pages. The second thing i understand that php needs to be on the server with apache and etc. i was jsut thinking about overcome to this problem, maybe if i would store php file on my server, and make one request to it, and that php file would make more http requests to where i need and it will returnev erything in one data to the js file. I just need a way get five www html websites into variables on my extension at almost same time , what is the better way to do it ?

someone ?\?

Comment: You are making AJAX requests to your own Chrome extension?  Why not just grab the data more directly, if it's locally available?

Comment: No i am making ajax request to same page on web but i thinking maybe it would be easier just to call request to your own file, and from that file call requests by php or etc to the web.

Comment: Basically what i need is to fetch infromation from webpage html and store it in local-storage but to fetch from few pages at almost same time.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clear up a thing or two. Files fetched from the World Wide Web are fetched from a server that's usually running Apache with a bunch of add-ons for stuff like executing PHP. The environment that your Chrome extension code runs in isn't any of that, so PHP won't run; it'll just get treated like any other text in the file. The only things that make your extension different from a plain HTML file loaded from the file:// protocol are the manifest.json file and some special privileges.

Now on to your question. It's not very clear, but it sounds like you were trying to use PHP to get around the fact that browsers won't let you directly fetch a file on another domain with Ajax. But Chrome *will* in fact allow a Chrome extension to do this, if it requests this permission. Head to [the Cross-Origin XMLHTTPRequest page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) and scroll down to "Requesting cross-origin permissions" for more information.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer but it was not what i meant, maybe i did not explained it clearly. What i meant is : I am having a problem with the link you send with http request (because i am doing like so now) that it works only with one request per some time or etc. and i need to fetch html from five pages. The second thing i understand that php needs to be on the server with apache and etc.

Comment: i was jsut thinking about overcome to this problem, maybe if i would store php file on my server, and make one request to it, and that php file would make more http requests to where i need and it will returnev erything in one data to the js file. I just need a way get five www html websites into variables on my extension at almost same time , what is the better way to do it ?